# Normalized and denormalized confusion in C

Tags: c, floating, denormalized

I'm brand new to C, and we're using it in a class to help us understand pretty low level computer systems.

I've been given the following problem, where all the code was given to me EXCEPT exp, frac, and the number being compared to x for each 'if' statement.

Verbatim:

> "You have been assigned the task of writing a C function to compute a floating-point representation of 2^x. You decide that the best way to do this is to directly construct the IEEE single-precision representation of the result. When x is too small, your routine will return 0.0. When x is too large, it will return +infinity. Fill in the blank portions of the code that follows to compute the correct result. Assume the function u2f returns a floating-point value having an identical bit representation as its unsigned argument."

```
float fpwr2(int x)
{
    /* Result exponent and fraction */
    unsigned exp frac;
    unsigned u;
    if (x< -126){
        /* Too small. Return 0.0 */
        exp = 00000000;
        frac = 00000000000000000000000;
    }else if (x< 1){
        /* Denormalized result */
        exp = 00000000;
        frac = ;
    }else if (x< 128){
        /* Normalized result */
        exp = ;
        frac = ;
    }else{
        /* Too big. Return +00 */
        exp = 11111111;
        frac = 00000000000000000000000;
    }
    /* Pack exp and frac into 32 bits */
    u = exp << 23 | frac;
    /* Return as float */
    return u2f(u);
}
```

I'm not asking anyone to do my homework for me. I'm lost. I'm fairly certain of a few of the blanks i filled in, but it seems to me that the blanks i have left open have dynamic solutions; that is to say, wouldn't the answer depend on x?

Please help me understand, i feel like it's a lot simpler than i realize!

Comment: Yes, the answer is going to depend on `x`. Do you know how to compute the solutions you want "by hand". Where are you having trouble in converting that to C code?

Comment: @hugomg I don't, i suppose that's where my problem is. It seems as though i would need to write a function to return the binary representation of x, but i believe it's simpler than that.

Comment: I got the impression that this exercise is precisely about writing a function to return the binary representation of x and not about finding a way to cheat using by casting a floating point variable back to an integer :)  First step is to learn how the IEEE floating point format works and the second step is to find a way to express that in C. btw, you on;y need to worry about how to write powers of two so the final result is not going to be too complicated.

Comment: wikipedia to the rescue?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format